# SubSelect MDX Query as filtered list of main query

Tags: subquery, mdx

SubSelect MDX Query as filtered list of main query

Hi all
I want to write MDX query like to SQL:

`select a, b, sum(x) 
   from table1
   where b = "True" and a in (select distinct c from table2 where c is not null and d="True")
   group by a,b`

I try something like this:

`Hi all
I want to write MDX query like to SQL:

`select a, b, sum(x) 
   from table1
   where b = "True" and a in (select distinct c from table2 where c is not null and d="True")
   group by a,b`

I try something like this:

```
    SELECT 
 NON EMPTY { [Measures].[X] } ON COLUMNS, 
 NON EMPTY { [A].[Name].[Name] 
  *[B].[Name].[Name].&[True]
  } ON ROWS
 FROM
 (
  SELECT 
    { ([A].[Name].[Name] ) } ON 0 
     FROM 
    ( SELECT ( 
        {EXCEPT([C].[Name].ALLMEMBERS, [C].[Name].[ALL].UNKNOWNMEMBER) }) ON COLUMNS 
        FROM
         ( SELECT ( 
         { [D].[Name].&[True] } ) ON COLUMNS 
         FROM [CUBE])) 
  )
```

But it returns me the sum of **x** from subquery.

How it should look like? '

Comment: Can you try changing [C].[Name].ALLMEMBERS to [C].[Name].[Name].MEMBERS? If that works I can explain further.

Comment: It doesn't work propertly.

Comment: can you elaborate? Error? Incorrect results?

Answer (score 1):

Does X's measure group have relationship with D dimension? If it's true, the following code must just work:

```
 Select 
 [Measures].[X] on 0, 
 Non Empty [A].[Name].[Name].Members * [B].[Name].&[True] on 1
 From [CUBE]
 Where ([D].[Name].&[True])
```

If you have many-to-many relationship, you need an extra measure (say Y):

```
Select 
[Measures].[X] on 0, 
Non Empty NonEmpty([A].[Name].[Name].Members,[Measures].[Y]) * [B].[Name].&[True] on 1
From [CUBE]
Where ([D].[Name].&[True])
```

Comment: No. X's measure group doesn't have relationship with D dimension.

Comment: It means you have to add a measure that has a relationship with A and D dimensions, so-called many-to-many relation. I've added an example.